# ERROR : Object of class WP_Error could not be converted to string

Tags: php, wordpress, fatal-error

Catchable fatal error: Object of class WP_Error could not be converted to string in /home/winentra/public_html/s1.ssonline.co.in/wp-content/themes/peekaboo/admin/common-functions.php on line 186

Line No. 186

```php
echo get_category_parents($cat, TRUE, ' ' . $delimiter . ' ');
```

Any ideas on this please?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please be careful, you title were poorly representative of what you were asking. Better writing would bring you better answers.

Answer (score 1):

Reason and Solution for this problem is [here](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/why-doesnt-this-if-statment-work-properly)

Answer (score 1):

The object you get returned if of a complex type that PHP is not able to convert into a string for printing.

Answer (score 1):

```
elseif ( is_single() && !is_attachment() && get_post_meta($post->ID, 'cust_cat', true) ) {
      $cat = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'cust_cat', true);
      echo $cat;
      echo $currentBefore;
      the_title();
      echo $currentAfter;

    } 

    elseif ( is_single() && !is_attachment() && !get_post_meta($post->ID, 'cust_cat', true) ) {
      $cat = get_the_category(); $cat = $cat[0];
      echo get_category_parents($cat, TRUE, ' ' . $delimiter . ' ');
      echo $currentBefore;
      the_title();
      echo $currentAfter;

    }
```

Comment: @iCodez I am getting an error similar to this: "Catchable fatal error: Object of class WP_Error could not be converted to string in /home/preprogrammer20/public_html/wp-includes/formatting.php on line 1025" I have tried everything but, nothing works. Can you please help me...? Where should i add the above codes ...?